# Deploy Rails Server and Python Server on the same Machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unix, deployment, python-server-pages

I have a normal rails server already deployed and is running on a ubuntu machine with port 80 for http service.

For the saving cost reason, I would like to run an internal python server on the same ubuntu machine at different port say 8888 and let the rails app call the api that python server expose.

I did this experiment on my local development machine and it worked fine. That is, I have my rails server run at localhost:3000 and python server run at localhost:8888. The rails server can call python api with no issue. However in production environment, I am struggling to make it work.

Any suggestion how should I set up the python server on production so that it can be access by rails server?

Comment: Have you checked your firewall/iptables?

Comment: Ideally, I would like to make it accessible by the rails application in the machine and not public. Following your suggestion, I check my iptable rules with [ sudo iptables -L ]. i don't see port 8888 open to tcp but only  port 80 of rails. I tried to open it up for tcp with command [ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT ]. It is however still not accessible.

Comment: Not necessarily public, just that localhost was allowed to do input and output on that port.(Check http://serverfault.com/a/247180/105425 ) If you run your python service elsewhere, does it work?

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm working on it.